# How to execute the Linux command from a TCL shell?

Tags: linux, tcl

I am executing following command successfully from linux env,

```
[UdayaShankar Das@lxapp-3]# tshark -r sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 94 00 00 0a 08 06 00 01
 08 00 06 04 00 01 00 10 94 00 00 0a c0 01 01 02
 00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00
 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

bu the above command failing when trying from tcl shell through exec command and back tik operator . Please advise.

```
% [ exec tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap  -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p' ]
 invalid command name "0-9a-f"
```

UPDATE:

thanks for your suggestion. I tried but seems not working :(

```
  % set cmd34 {tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'}
 tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'
 % [ eval exec $cmd34]
 invalid command name "0-9a-f"
```

Also tried with second option

```
%set cmd34 {tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'}
 tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'
 % [ exec {*}$cmd34 ]
 extra characters after close-brace
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a chunk of shell script like this:

```sh
tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap  -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'
```

The simplest method of running it is to use:

```
set shellscript {tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap  -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p'}
set response [exec /bin/sh -c $shellscript]
```

Alternatively, change the single quote characters to braces:

```
exec tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap  -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n {s/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p}
```

Comment: The complaint is because in your code, you have `[0-9a-f]`, which Tcl interprets as a command invocation if you don't quote it properly.

Comment: Yes, I am missing something.. I tried both of your suggestion but still seeing issue like follwong

sed: -e expression #1, char 45: unterminated `s'

Comment: The sed expression seems to have been munged. `s/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p` shouldn't become `s/^[0-9a-f]*s((s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]){1,16}).*^A/p`, right?

Comment: Yes, now I added backward slashes, but still seeing the issue

`% set cmd34 {tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*\1/p'}
 tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*\1/p'
% [exec /bin/sh -c $cmd34]
sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unterminated `s'`

Comment: @udayashankar: there is still a regular slash missing between `.*` and `\1`: it should be `.*/\1`. That's why the `s` expression is unterminated.

Comment: Thanks @Hoodiecrow .corrected but  getting response with a message as invalid command, any suggestons
`% set cmd34 {tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'}
tshark -r /home/arts2/STC_CAPTURE/sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'
% [exec /bin/sh -c  $cmd34]`

Comment: invalid command name " ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 10 94 00 00 0a 08 06 00 01  08 00 06 04 00 01 00 10 94 00 00 0a c0 01 01 02  00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 01 01 01 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"

Comment: @udayashankar: the brackets around `exec /bin/sh -c $cmd34` tells the Tcl shell to attempt to run *the result of the command* as a command. In the answers above, the brackets were used because the `exec` command was invoked from within another command invocation. Try just writing `exec /bin/sh -c $cmd34` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the command into a variable and use `{*}` or `eval` to evaluate it.

```
set cmd {tshark -r sim_venom_sanity_DEVICE1_PORT1_1_capture.pcap -Vx -R frame.number==2 | sed -n 's/^[0-9a-f]*\s\(\(\s[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)\{1,16\}\).*$/\1/p'}
puts [ eval exec $cmd ]
```

If you have a tcl 8.5 or higher , you can use the below code, instead of `eval`

```
puts [ exec {*}$cmd ] ; # {*} is for argument expansion which is recommended
```

Please note that the expression is enclosed with braces to avoid any substitutions and treat them as literal values. If you need to use braces in the expression, make sure you are escaping it with backslash  like `\{`

Comment: Don't use single quotes (unless you're passing the string to the shell as a subprocess). Braces have the equivalent function in Tcl.